# javascript grade calculator using arrays and functions clarification

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, average

I am trying to write a program that will display the letter grade once user inputs a real or float number. Prompt question works but the function is not working.  I tried debugging the code with no success.

Any help is welcomed. Thanks!

```js
    var nameData = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
    var nameDataLength = nameData.length;
    var avgGrade = 0;
    var gradeDate = prompt('Enter your grade to check your letter grade');

    function getAvg(nameData, gradeData) {
      for (var i = 0; i < nameData.length; i++) {
        alert("Your grades are " + nameData[i] + " ," + gradeData[i]);
        if (gradeData[i] >= 90) {
          alert("Your grades are " + nameData[i] + "A");
        } else if (gradeData[i] >= 80) {
          alert("Your grades are " + nameData[i] + "B");
        } else if (gradeData[i] >= 70) {
          alert("Your grades are " + nameData[i] + "C");
        } else if (gradeData[i] >= 60) {
          alert(" Your grades are " + nameData[i] + "D");
        } else {
          alert("Your grades are " + nameData[i] + "F");
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question? What exactly do you need help with? How did you try to debug it?

Comment: It would be good if you could add your expected output too because I don't know what you're trying to do with your code.

Comment: how do you invoke the `getAvg` function? coz all you need to do is to call your function sometime after your prompt

Comment: I have just started using JS so I am not sure what I am doing wrong, to be honest. The question prompt is working correctly, but I cannot store or get any responses back. I am not sure how to correct the function.

Comment: Note `gradeData` doesn't exist. Your variable is called `gradeDate`.

Comment: My expectation is an alert that will display the letter grade once user enters a number, using a function. I am not familiar with functions and I am pretty sure there may be an error in my function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look on this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>


    function myFunction() {

    var gradeData = prompt('Enter your grade to check your letter grade');
    var grade=getGrade(gradeData);
    alert(grade);
    }
    function getGrade(gradeData) {
        if (gradeData >= 90) {
            return 'A';
        }
        if (gradeData >= 80) {
            return 'B';
        }
        if (gradeData >= 70) {
            return 'C';
        }
        if (gradeData >= 60) {
            return 'D';
        }
        return 'F';
    }

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

The other way you can modify your code like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to type in your Marks and get grades.</p>

<button onclick="gradeCalculator()">Click here</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var nameData = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F'];   

function gradeCalculator() {
var gradeData = prompt('Enter your grade to check your letter grade');
getAvg(nameData,gradeData);
}

function getAvg(nameData, gradeData) {        
        if (gradeData>= 90) {
          alert("Your grades are " + nameData[0]);
        } else if (gradeData >= 80) {
          alert("Your grades are " + nameData[1]);
        } else if (gradeData >= 70) {
          alert("Your grades are " + nameData[2]);
        } else if (gradeData >= 60) {
          alert(" Your grades are " + nameData[3]);
        } else {
          alert("Your grades are " + nameData[4]);
        }

    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider to take a function for getting a grade out of a given percent value.

This function features an early return, because if a value is found the function could be terminated without testing other values.

This pattern prevents to use a continuing `if ... else if ... else if ...` pattern, because only false condition goes on with checking.

```js
function getGrade(percent) {
    if (percent >= 90) {
        return 'A';
    }
    if (percent >= 80) {
        return 'B';
    }
    if (percent >= 70) {
        return 'C';
    }
    if (percent >= 60) {
        return 'D';
    }
    return 'F';
}

console.log(getGrade(90)); // A
console.log(getGrade(81)); // B
console.log(getGrade(72)); // C
console.log(getGrade(63)); // D
console.log(getGrade(54)); // F
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems:

- typo: `nameDate` -> `nameData`
- you never call your function
- your function does not do what you think it does

I will solve the first two so that you can see the third.

```js
var nameData = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
var nameDataLength = nameData.length;
var avgGrade = 0;

function getAvg(gradeData) {
  for (var i = 0; i < nameData.length; i++) {
    alert("Your grades are " + nameData[i] + " ," + gradeData[i]);
    if (gradeData[i] >= 90) {
      alert("Your grades are " + nameData[i] + "A");
    } else if (gradeData[i] >= 80) {
      alert("Your grades are " + nameData[i] + "B");
    } else if (gradeData[i] >= 70) {
      alert("Your grades are " + nameData[i] + "C");
    } else if (gradeData[i] >= 60) {
      alert(" Your grades are " + nameData[i] + "D");
    } else {
      alert("Your grades are " + nameData[i] + "F");
    }
  }
}


var gradeData = prompt('Enter your grade to check your letter grade');
// you need to actually call the function.
getAvg(gradeData);
```